# Numeric Matching / Extracting with Hard Coded Values in R

Tags: r

Having trouble understanding numeric matching / indexing in R.

If I have a situation where I create a dataframe such as:

```
options(digits = 3)
x <- seq(from = 0, to = 5, by = 0.10)
TestDF <- data.frame(x = x, y = dlnorm(x))
```

and I wanted to compare a hardcoded value to my y column -

```
> TestDF[TestDF$y == 0.0230,]$x
numeric(0)
```

That being said, if I compare to the value that's straight out of the dataframe (which for an x value of 4.9, should be a y value of 0.0230).

```
> TestDF[TestDF$y == TestDF[50,]$y,]$x
[1] 4.9
```

Does this have to do with exact matching? If I limit the digits to 3 decimal point, then 0.0230000 won't be the same as the original value in y I'm comparing to? If this is the case, is there a way around it if I do need to extract values based on rounded, hard-coded values?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `round()` function to reduce the number of decimal digits to the preferred scale of the floating point number. See below.

```
set.seed(1L)
x <- seq(from = 0, to = 5, by = 0.10)
TestDF <- data.frame(x = x, y = dlnorm(x))
constant <- 0.023
TestDF[ with(TestDF, round(y, 3) == constant), ]
#      x          y
# 50 4.9 0.02302884
```

Answer (score 1):

You can compare the rounded `y` with the stated value:

```
> any(TestDF$y == 0.0230)
[1] FALSE
> any(round(TestDF$y, 3) == 0.0230)
[1] TRUE
```

I'm not certain you grok the meaning of the `digits` option. From `?options` it says about `digits`

> `digits`: controls the number of significant digits to **print** when printing numeric values.

(emphasis mine.) So this only affects how the values are *printed*, not how they are stored.

You generated a set of reals, none of which are exactly `0.0230`. This has nothing to do with exact matching. The value you indicated should be `0.0230` is actually stored as

```
> with(TestDF, print(y[50], digits = 22))
[1] 0.02302883835550340041465
```

regardless of the `digits` setting in `options` *because* that setting only affects the *printed* value. And the issue is not exact matching because even with the small fudge allowed by the recommended way to do comparisons, `all.equal()`, `y[50]` and `0.0230` are still not equal

```
> with(TestDF, all.equal(0.0230, y[50]))
[1] "Mean relative difference: 0.001253842"
```